# Non www to www redirect still important (seo - duplicate content)?

Tags: seo

Is a redirect from the non www version of the website to the www version still needed for seo reasons (duplicate content)? In the google search console i set the www version as my preferred version.

Comment: Sorry but we already similar questions already on Pro Webmasters. If your looking for information that is more current then we have several ways that old questions can attract new or improved answers, this includes quality edits and bounties. Please visit our help centre for further help.

Comment: Thank you but this answer is two years old. You know a lot changes in two years in seo and i would like to have an updated opinion on this topic. Is this possible?

Comment: The great thing about Stack Exchange Q&A sites is that users can choose to add more relevant and current answers at anytime. If the answers are old then thats because no one as of yet as left a newer answer, anyone can do so at anytime and we allow bounties to be run on questions to attract more attention and new answers. You lack the rep to run your own bounty on the question but stick around, earn some rep and your be able to run bounties on everything you want to know. I'm actually leaving a more current answer now.

Comment: I've added a new answer here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22213/www-and-non-www-can-suffer-duplicated-content/100710#100710 John's answer may be dated 2011 but its still current and valid. I've added more attention info to enforce why those usages are still current.